# fstream and iostream error when compiling

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, fstream, iostream, dev-c++

when compiling a file with iostream or fstream included, devc++ will open a file, which i guess is the file containing information about the library, and say that there's an error

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2\include\c++\bits \ostream_insert.h  [Error] '__try' was not declared in this scope

i have already tried with different files, but everything with iostream or fstream won't compile.

i tried uninstall/reinstall, and the first compilations went ok. when i reopened devc++, and tried to compile again, the same error came up

Comment: It's hard to guess what may cause this, what platform are you compiling from and to, what IDE do you use, perhaps a CMake file? :)

Comment: @Plegeus i'm the kind of high school student who solves easy programming problems, never went far enough in to reply. I guess the platform is windows, devc++, i have no idea of what an IDE or a CMake file can be. Thanks for help, but i guess i'll have to find another solution if the complexity is at this level XD

Comment: My guess is that there is some conflict between toolchains, it is hard to explain, but there are different sets of tools that a programmer can use to run C or C++ (very closely related) programs, examples are MinGW and MSVC. Devc++ is probably trying to make MinGW work with something else which will fail and give these kinds of issues... Why precisely are you using devc++ and what is it exactly you want your program to do? (an IDE is an Integrated Development Environment)

Comment: right now anything I try to compile with iostream or fstream doesn't. even when I don't put any of these libraries' function in the code. I would almost say the library "files" have something wrong, or the compiler "doesn't understand" what is written there.

Comment: Your intuition is very much right! Looks more like a linker problem (a linker is a program which looks for functions in parts of your code to "tell" other code where to find this code...). Programming in C on windows can be a real hassle... I recommend you switch to either Visual Studio (spcialiased in C/C++ development and other things on windows, or CLion which gives you much more control, I believe if you use your school email you can get CLion for free too! Otherwise you might want to look up something like devc++ toolchains or something.

Comment: thank you so much for your time and suggestions! My teacher said the quickest solution might be to use a virtual machine. i'll anyway try some methods.